# Как уменьшить чувствительность триггера str в zabbix

Tags: zabbix

На сервере Zabbix (версия 3.2.1) имеется элемент данных типа log, который собирается раз в 30 сек.
В данный лог попадают события: "Разрыв соединения" и "Установка соединения".

Для этого элемента создан триггер, который работает.
Но очень часто эти 2 события идут подряд. То есть соединение упало и тут же восстановилось.
Приходят сразу 2 сообщения от zabbix. Как переписать триггер так чтобы он срабатывал только если есть событие "Разрыв соединения", а события "Установка соединения" не идет следом?

Выражение проблемы

```
{TRANSFILE_2017:log["D:\FC_Run.log"," --- ",windows-1251].str(Разрыв)}=1
```

Выражение восстановления

```
{TRANSFILE_2017:log["D:\FC_Run.log"," --- ",windows-1251].str(Установка)}=1
```

Tags: None

Answer (score 2):

Можно сделать так:

```
{TRANSFILE_2017:log["D:\FC_Run.log"," --- ",windows-1251].str(Разрыв,#2)}=1 and
{TRANSFILE_2017:log["D:\FC_Run.log"," --- ",windows-1251].str(Разрыв)}=0 and
{TRANSFILE_2017:log["D:\FC_Run.log"," --- ",windows-1251].str(Установка)}=0
```

Если в двух последних сообщениях есть разрыв, но разрыв не в самом последнем сообщении (то есть разрыв в предпоследнем сообщении), и в последнем сообщении нет установки.

Comment: Но может быть ситуация, когда Разрыв один и на него надо среагировать.

Comment: Не совсем понял вашу мысль. Можете привести пример логов, на которые надо реагировать?

Comment: 10/05/2019 08:46:33   I   20000009          003: --- Установка соединения со XXX Server ,7772. Версия сервера 22.21.20.

10/05/2019 08:46:33   E   40000009          004: --- Разрыв соединения со XXX Server.

Comment: Надо реагировать если после события разрыв прошло больше одной минуты, а события установка нет.